# MATLAB add a letter at the end of every string of a cell array of string

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

Let's say I've a cell array of string:

```
A = {'hello','world','how','are','you'};
```

I want to add the letter `z` at the end of every string, in order to obtain:

```
Az = {'helloz','worldz','howz','arez','youz'};
```

I'm using a for loop to accomplish this task, however I would like to **improve it** as much as possible.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
Az = cell(size(A)); % Preload
for i = 1:size(A,2)
    Az{i} = [A{i},'z'];
end
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you want to improve the loop I suggest [not using `i` as a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab), to eliminate the loop entirely, try [`cellfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`strcat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) does just that:

```
Az = strcat(A, 'z');
```

From the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html),

> `s = strcat(s1,...,sN)` horizontally concatenates strings `s1`,...,`sN`. Each input argument can be a single string, a collection of strings in a cell array, or a collection of strings in a character array.
>
> If any input argument is a cell array, the result is a cell array of strings. Otherwise, the result is a character array.
>
> For character array inputs, `strcat` removes trailing ASCII white-space characters: space, tab, vertical tab, newline, carriage return, and form feed. For cell array inputs, strcat does not remove trailing white space.